# screen.png: error: failed reading from input: PNG chunk type is too large?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Normally the compilation of my app works. but when I execute the command:

```
ionic cordova build --release android
```

I get this error.

[image]

How can I solve that? Thank you

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?